# Create a single logical volume from 2 external hdd's

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, lvm, rsync

I have an Ubuntu 17.04 with LVM enabled installation on a Linux server (but running Ubuntu desktop at present). It has 5 physical drives, but 1 logical volume of 7.2Tb.

I would like to set up an rsync backup onto 2 external hdd's (each 3.7Tb in size).  I expect this will be easier if I could mount the two (permanent) external hdd's as a single logical volume, otherwise I can't imagine how I would manage the data over two separate volumes with rsync.

Is it possible to create a single logical volume from two external hdd's, if not, is it possible instead for rsync to accommodate having two separate drives to write to?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is BTRFS. [Here is a guide](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices) to lead you in the right direction in terms of combining physical devices into a single logical one (on the fly even).

Comment: Btrfs is so buggy as with my experience with it from 4 weeks ago. I wouldn't recommend. OP should stick to ext4 and lvm.

Comment: I have LVM enabled as part of my install, would anybody be able to point me towards the correct procedure?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it should work the way you describe. Setting it up would be just like setting up the LVM you've already got on your internal disks, but on your external ones. I recommend using a different volume group, though; I don't know how Linux would react if you tried to extend the current volume group onto removable disks that will (presumably) not be permanently attached to the computer. That said, I've never attempted this, so there may be something I'm overlooking.

A second option would be to use Linux's software RAID tools, which enable combining multiple devices into one device. For your purpose, you'd want to do RAID 0 (striping). [This Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID) covers RAID. It's focused on OS installation, but it should be helpful if you go with this approach. Note that both RAID striping and LVM would make your backup data more vulnerable to disk failures -- if you lose one disk, you could lose access to the entire backup set.

A third option would be to use a backup tool or technique that enables splitting data across multiple volumes. The standard `tar` utility can do this. You'd need to use its `-M` (`--multi-volume`) option. (IIRC, there's also an option to specify the volume size, but I don't see it on a quick scan of the `tar` manpage. I may be misremembering or I may have overlooked that option.) One caveat: This `tar` feature was originally intended for use with backup tapes, not hard disks. I don't know offhand how well it would work with disks. You might need to use it with the raw disk device (`/dev/sdf` or whatever), not a file on a filesystem, and swap the backup disks so that only one is attached at any given moment. There are almost certainly other backup tools with similar features, but none spring immediately to mind. You could do something similar in a manual way by figuring out how much disk space is used by different directories and backing them up manually to each backup disk. (You'd use filesystems, and could attach both disks simultaneously, with this approach.)